# Change java source version for multiple project using same sonar scanner

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have 3 different projects. One of them is based on java 1.6 and the others are using java 8 features. I have **sonar-scanner** locally and running the analysis by using scripts (no Maven or Gradle is being used). I have configured the **sonar.java.source** to be 1.6.

My problem is that **same runner** is being used to analyze the other 2 projects (java 8 ones). How can I change the version of the java source for the other ones? I don't want to manually change it each time I want to run the runner.
Can I somehow pass it as parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Source version is not a property of the scanner, but of the projects. Configure these values in your pom, or your `sonar-project.properties` files, or in the command line arguments (`-Dsonar.java.source=1.x`), but not in the SonarQube Scanner properties.